# jquery datepicker - selected date plus 6 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I currently have the following code which selects the week number of the selected date and also the selected date:

```
$(this).val("Week Number " + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)) + " - " + $.datepicker.formatDate('d M yy', new Date(dateText)));
```

outputting something like:

`Week Number 41 - 8 Oct 2012`

What I would like to achieve is something like the following

`Week Number 41 - 8 Oct to 14 Oct 2012`

So selected date to selected date + 6 days.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(this).val( "Week Number " + 
          $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)) + 
            " - " + $.datepicker.formatDate('d M', new Date(dateText)) +
            " to " + 
            $.datepicker.formatDate('d M y', new Date(new Date(dateText).getTime() +
                                           6*24*60*60*1000) )
));
```

**Edit:**  changed 7 days to 6 days.

Comment: Hi Sir, i don't understand what is the code 6*24*60*60*1000, can you explain what's the meaning of that? thank you. .

Comment: This is the time we want to add to current time, expressed in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sixDaysTime = new Date();
var origDate = new Date(dateText);

sixDaysTime.setDate(origDate.getDate()+6);

$(this).val("Week Number " + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(origDate)) + " - " + $.datepicker.formatDate('d M yy', origDate) + " To " + $.datepicker.formatDate('d M yy', sixDaysTime));
```